# How to implement method with expression parameter c#

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I want to create a method like this:

```
var result = database.Search<EntityType>(x=>x.Name, "Entity Name field value");
result = database.Search<EntityType>(x=>x.Id, "Entity Id field value");
result = database.Search<EntityType2>(x=>x.Id, "Entity2 Id field value");
result = database.Search<EntityTypeAny>(x=>x.FieldAny, "EntityAny FieldAny value");
```

How can I implement this method?

Comment: you want to create a method that works similarly to the `Search()` method, in a generic way?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can turn a selector and value into a predicate using `Expression.Equal`:

```
static IQueryable<TSource> Search<TSource, TValue>(
    this IQueryable<TSource> source,
    Expression<Func<TSource,TValue>> selector,
    TValue value)
{
    var predicate = Expression.Lambda<Func<TSource,bool>>(
        Expression.Equal(
            selector.Body,
            Expression.Constant(value, typeof(TValue))
        ), selector.Parameters);
    return source.Where(predicate);
}
```

Then you just need to do something like:

```
var result = database.SomeEntities.Search(x => x.SomeProp, "value");
```

If you want to do it from the *database*, then that depends on what the database *is*; for example, with LINQ-to-SQL you could add an additional method:

```
static IQueryable<TSource> Search<TSource, TValue>(
    this System.Data.Linq.DataContext database,
    Expression<Func<TSource, TValue>> selector,
    TValue value) where TSource : class
{
    IQueryable<TSource> source = database.GetTable<TSource>();
    return Search(source, selector, value);
}
```

and use:

```
var result = database.Search<SomeEntity, string>(x => x.SomeProp, "value");
```

frankly I think it is clearer to use the `database.SomeEntities` version, though.

Answer (score 1):

I can only think of this (with 2 generic arguments)

```
    public static IEnumerable<TModel> Search<TModel, TValue>(
        Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression,
        TValue value
    )
    {
        return new List<TModel>();
    }
```

usage

```
var result = Search<EntityType, int>(x => x.Id, 1);
var result2 = Search<EntityType, string>(x => x.Name, "The name");
```

you can replace TValue with object to avoid the second generic argument, but I would stick with this.

Btw. this works great in conjunction with this little helper

```
public static class ExpressionHelpers
{
    public static string MemberName<T, V>(this Expression<Func<T, V>> expression)
    {
        var memberExpression = expression.Body as MemberExpression;
        if (memberExpression == null)
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Expression must be a member expression");

        return memberExpression.Member.Name;
    }
}
```

Now you can get the Name of the Property (Id oder Name) in this example by calling

```
var name = expression.MemberName();
```

Comment: What if the second parameter is always a bool, than you can maybe use it like: var result2 = Search<EntityType>(x => x.Name == "The name");

Comment: why would the OP need to extract the member name in this scenario? it seems to me that they just need to construct the predicate

Comment: @Marc: that was not part of the question, but I assumed that's what the OP needs to know in the Search method, for example to build an SQL query.

Answer (score 0):

do you want types to dynamic

```
public ReturnType Read<ReturnType>(string FieldName, object dfVal)
{
    if (Res.IsDBNull(Res.GetOrdinal(FieldName)))
        return dfVal;
    try {
        return (ReturnType)Res.GetValue(Res.GetOrdinal(FieldName));
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        return dfVal;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a part of what he wants, He wants to specify the type indeed, but also want to use a predicate like LinQ can.

Comment: it is genuinely unclear to me if/how this answers the question asked