# apply linq filter converting expressions

Tags: linq, linq-to-entities, entity-framework-5

I have a nice Linq challenge. I would like to filter some data on a Date using a FilterFunction. It should work like this:

```
ApplyDateFilterEx(query,null, DateTime.Today, s => s.CreatedDate);
```

Should filter the query so that all 'shipments' until today are returned. The query object is of IQueryable and the whole query should be evaluated by EF5 and therefore should convert to SQL.

This is what I have so far  (DOES NOT COMPILE):

```
private static IQueryable<Shipment> ApplyDateFilterEx(IQueryable<Shipment> query, DateTime? minDate, DateTime? maxDate, Expression<Func<Shipment, DateTime?>> dateMember)
    {
        if (minDate != null)
        {
            //convert func to expression so EF understands
            Expression<Func<Shipment, bool>> where = x => minDate <= dateMember(x);
            query = query.Where(where);
        }
        if (maxDate != null)
        {
            Expression<Func<Shipment, bool>> where = x => dateMember(x) <= maxDate;
            query = query.Where(where);
        }

        return query;
    }
```

You can see I want to convert the expression s=>DateTime? to s=> Bool to be evaluated. How can I get this to work?

Thank you for reading.
Martijn

UDPATE: 
I ended up with this (thanks to rdvanbuuren)

```
 var predicate = Expression.Lambda<Func<Shipment, bool>>(
                    Expression.GreaterThanOrEqual(
                        selector.Body,
                        Expression.Constant(dateFilter.MinDate, typeof (DateTime?))
                        ), selector.Parameters);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at
[How to implement method with expression parameter c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16436558/how-to-implement-method-with-expression-parameter-c-sharp)

I think that's exactly what you need, but with an Expression.GreaterThanOrEqual or Expression.LessThanOrEqual. Good luck!